# Rotate then move object in Random direction in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, 2d

I am trying to create a script in Unity that when another object touches it, it grabs the object, rotates it in a random direction, and launches it, but I only want to rotate and launch the other object on the z axis.

Here is my script:

```
public BallController ballController;
private GameObject ball;
private Rigidbody2D ballRb;

 void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    ball = other.gameObject;
    ballRb = ball.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    ball.transform.position = this.transform.position;
    // Freeze the ball
    ballRb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
    // Rotate the ball
    ball.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, Random.Range(0, 360));
    // Start moving the ball again
    ballRb.velocity = ballRb.velocity * ballController.bulletSpeed * Time.deltatime;

}
```

The other script (The ball) is has a Ridgidbody and is launched by another object into this one, the script gets the ball to rotate how I want to, but it won't get the ball moving again.

The ballController is set in the editor and the bulletSpeed is just an int that I want the ball to travel at (currently set to 6).

Comment: The velocity is zero that is why it is not moving.  Check the bulletSpeed and deltatime but I believe it is due to setting the velocity to Vector2.zero.  for the object to move in the z direction the x and y component of the vector has to be zero and the z component has to be non zero.

Comment: I just tried disabling it and now the ball moves but the random rotation stopped working, now it grabs the ball, doesn't rotate it, and sends it off again.

Comment: @jdweng I doubt you want to throw something in `z` direction in a 2D game ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with `Rigidbody2D` you shouldn't use the `transform` for setting the rotation but rather use [`ballRb.rotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-rotation.html).

Later you are using

```
ballRb.velocity = ballRb.velocity * ballController.bulletSpeed * Time.deltatime;
```

but right before you have set

```
ballRb = Vector2.zero;
```

So the multiplication results in `Vector2.zero`. Also adding [`Time.deltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html)(typo btw) in this one-time assignment makes no sense.

Also if you remove this line you are not taking the new rotation into account when assigning a new velocity.

The `velocity` is in global space. You also can't use e.g. `transform.right` as new direction since the transform isn't updated .. the `Rigidbody2D` is .. so you can use [`GetRelativeVector`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.GetRelativeVector.html) in order to set the new local direction after rotating

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D ball)
{
    // The assignment of the GameObject
    // was kind of redundant except
    // you need the reference for something else later

    var ballRb = ball.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

    // set position through RigidBody component
    ballRb.position = this.transform.position;

    // Rotate the ball using the Rigidbody component
    // Was the int overload intented here? Returning int values 0-359
    // otherwise rather use the float overload by passing float values as parameters
    ballRb.rotation = Random.Range(0f, 360f);

    // Start moving the ball again
    // with a Vector different to Vector2.zero 
    // depending on your setup e.g.
    ballRb.velocity = ballRb.GetRelativeVector(Vector2.right * ballController.bulletSpeed);
}
```

little demo

[image]

for the walls btw I used something very similar:

```
var ballRb = ball.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
var newDirection = Vector2.Reflect(ballRb.velocity, transform.up);
ballRb.rotation = ballRb.rotation + Vector2.SignedAngle(ballRb.velocity, newDirection);
ballRb.velocity = newDirection.normalized * ballController.bulletSpeed;
```

Comment: Thank you for the information, I'm a noob so not everything you stated above makes sense, your script works however the ball bounces to the right every first touch and the only launches it in a random direction after the first touch (Mean the second, thrid etc).

Comment: Hey just upated the code .. I was wrong about the `FixedUpdate` .. ofcourse the collision itself already **is** is FixedUpdate since this is Physics already ;)

Comment: Ah, thank you, I will mark your answer as correct but I'd like to ask 2 things first if you don't mind, can you explain what you mean by " Was the int overload intented here? Returning int values 0-359"? And are you sure that the launch direction is completely random? As I'm testing it I find it only tends to launch in about 5 directions.

Comment: @UltraGamer I'm pretty sure it is random ;) For [`RandomRange`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html) have a look at the linked API. There are two versions, one taking `int` as parameter and also returning an `int` value (here the second parameter is **exclusive**), the other one taking and returning `float` values. If using `Random.Range(0, 360)` the values will always be full `int` angles so a random value from `0, 1, 2, 3, ... ,359`. If rather using `Random.Range(0f, 360f)` the angle can be any float value in the range `0-360` so e.g. `0.25f` or `359.888`

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, I wasn't able to get the walls to work using the script at the bottom of your answer but that's ok, thank you!

Comment: yeah I was lazy ;) you have to rotate the walls so their local `Y` vector always points to the center of the screen ;) this way the `Vector2.Reflect(ballRb.velocity, transform.up);` should work as expected

Comment: Their local Y Vector? Do you mean the walls Y-axis?

Comment: yes exactly so I simply made one wall, copied it and then did: top wall has rotation `0,0,180`, bottom wall has `0,0,0`, right wall has `0,0,-90` and left has `0,0,90` ;) You might btw also get rid of `ballRb.position = this.transform.position;` I don't know your specific use case but it might look strange if your obstacles are bigger .. I would just leave the ball in its current position

Comment: My wall is 0,0,0 and it still doesn't work, it reverses the Y axis so if the ball was headed down it starts going up, but it doesn't change the X so the ball goes through it and continues going.

Comment: hm sorry buddy this is hard to tell without actually sitting in front of it. Maybe checking out [`Vector2.Reflect`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.Reflect.html) helps you to understand what is going on there

Comment: ok, thank you for all your help anyway, I couldn't have done this without you!